# Unable to alter or populate the value attribute of input tag in html using console window

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a website on which I want to populate or alter the input field with my text from the console window but I don't know why the the code shown below doesn't work for me.

```
var k = document.getElementsByClassName("persist writer-input")[0]; 
// populate or alter 
k.value = "My text value"
```

relevant code used on the website.

```
<form class="connected writer" data-v-98381900>
    <span class="writer-room"
        data-v-98381900>Lounge
    </span>
    <input
        maxlength="500" class="persist writer-input" placeholder="Type to chat, or drop an image to share" type="search"
        data-v-98381900>
</form>
```

Demonstration of the issue.

**CASE 1:**

[image]

**CASE 2:**

[image]

*Notice the text appends or populates for a while but the effect doesn't persist.*

Note: The website works fine if I do it manually from the keyboard and the problem occurs from the console window only, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your website using any UI frameworks or libraries?

Comment: It looks like `vue` with its `data-v` attribute... It might be keeping this value safe from this kind of interference?

Comment: Yes it is using, JS  Framework: Vue.js, CDN: Cloudflare, Web framework: Express and JS Library : core-js 3.6.5

Comment: Can you include the Vue code backing your input element?

Comment: actually, I am pretty sure that website uses Vuejs also the value of the input field is synced with the internal state so if you modify the input element it'll notice it's out of sync and restore it, there's a two-way binding between javascript and the input field, that's what I concluded as of now, but as I don't have website code I am inspecting so still thinking how to update Vuejs input tag value from console